# Is 5.0 an integer or decimal number?

Tags: integers, decimal-expansion

Is 5.0 an integer or decimal number? I was asked by one of my friends, we got both confused.

I said by definition integer contains no or zero decimal part so it should be an integer. But he said that 5.0 contains decimal point so it should be a decimal number.

Now I am wondering who is correct, I surfed on internet but didn't find like which one is correct? Please help me in this.

Answer (score 2):

Why not both?

Calling a number *integer* refers to its value. Calling a number a *decimal* refers to the way it was written down.

5.0 is an integer number written in the decimal notation.

Comment: but it can be either a decimal number or integer right?

Decimal numbers and integers are mutually exclusive sets right?

Comment: They are not. As I've said, these terms refer to different qualities of the number: it's value and the way it was written down. Are *red* and *round*, that refer to an object's color and shape, mutually exclusive?

Comment: The key idea is how the word *decimal* is defined. It would seem that if it means expressing numbers as digital multiples of integral powers of $10,$ then both $5$ and $5.0$ are integers and decimal. My point is that it's not the $.0$ that makes it a decimal, under this definition. If we instead define decimal as only *nonzero* digital multiples of *negative integral* powers of $10,$ then neither $5$ no $5.0$ are decimals. The lesson is that it all depends on how things are defined. So that's what one should ask OP: How do you define *decimal.*

Comment: @Allawonder,  I read somewhere as "A decimal number is a number that has a decimal mark", according to that 5.0 is a decimal number

But it raises another question: What do we call numbers with non-zero decimal part?

Comment: @prat That's alright, though I wouldn't call that a very nice definition. But again, I wouldn't know why that definition was made, so it's alright by the definer. As to the question of what you call numbers like $5.2,$ why that's just a rational number expressed as a decimal.

Comment: @Allawonder, as you said that "I wouldn't call that a very nice definition", but then accoridng to you what are decimal numbers?

Comment: @prat OK, you call a number *decimal* if it's written with a decimal mark (clearly you refer to the way the number was written down). That's basically the same definition that I use (although, to be precise, one needs to also specify what digits can be used in notation etc.). And how do you define *integer*?

Comment: @Allawonder integer is a number with no or zero decimal part.

Comment: @prat If you define integers as nomber written with no or zero decimal part, then 5.0 is still an integer number, because it has 0 decimal part. As I've said, it's both: It is written in decimal notation (so it's a decimal number) but has zero decimal part (so it's an integer).

However it should be noted, that this is not the way the integer numbers are defined. Without citing the formal definition (which is a bit complex), the definition relies on the value of the number (which is an abstract property independent on the way the number was written down).

Comment: so you are saying 5.0 is not a integer?

Comment: @prat According to your definition, it is, let me cite myself: **5.0 is still an integer number, because it has 0 decimal part**. According to the standard definition it also is integer, though because of its value, not because of the way it is wriiten.

Comment: @prat According to me a decimal number is simply a number expressed as a series of the form $$\sum_i c_i10^i,$$ where the coefficients $c_i$ are any of the digits $0,1,2,\ldots, 9.$

Comment: @Allawonder That's not a good definition. Note that expression like $a.b$ is not the same as the expression $a\cdot 10^0+b\cdot 10^{-1}$. Both expresions have the same value, but they are different expressions.

I would define a decimal number as two sequences of decimal digits (the first one has to be finite) separated by a decimal mark (that is an expression of the form $a_ma_{m-1}\dots a_1a_0.b_1b_2\dots b_{n-1}b_n$ where $a_i$ and $b_i$ are digits from the set $\{0,\dots 9\}$).

Comment: @AdamLatosiński On the contrary, those expressions are equivalent. You can think of expressions like $abcde.fghij...$ as abbreviations of the series defined above.

Comment: @Allawonder Equivalent in the sense of value, but different in the sense of symbols used.

Comment: @AdamLatosiński And what does that matter? You might as well say the numbers expressed in some other language are different!

Comment: @Allawonder Numbers are the same in the sense of value, but when they are expressed in a different ways. And being a decimal property of the expression. If you change the expression, it may stop being a decimal number, even if its value does not change.

Comment: @AdamLatosiński Changing the expressions here doesn't change anything. Your notation is simply an abbreviation of mine. Please research this independently.